# How to use LDAP to store sudoer information

Tags: ldap, sudoers

We have a LDAP server and lots working servers. Our user's info are in LDAP http://fclose.com/b/281/ . But sudoers list is stored in /etc/sudoers. Now the question is, how to store sudoers list in LDAP so that there is a center control of it?

We are using Fedora 12 on both LDAP server and working servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the official instructions from [README.LDAP](http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/readme_ldap.html), and the [`sudoers.ldap`](http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/sudoers.ldap.man.html) manual page.

1. Make sure `sudo` is built with LDAP support.
2. Update the LDAP schema.
3. Import `sudoers` file into LDAP.
4. Configure the `sudoers` service in `nsswitch.conf`.

Comment: Are there any GUI based apps for managing Sudoer Rules in LDAP? Using a LDAP Browser is not a very user-friendly way for managing a large number of Sudo Rules. FreeIPA has a UI for managing Sudoer Rules, but it requires 389 Directory Server, and we don't use that in our environment (for good reasons)

Comment: `README.LDAP` link is dead, so as `sudoers.ldap` link.

Answer (score 3):

Add sudo entry like below

```
dn: ou=sudoers,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
ou: sudoers
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit

dn: cn=sudogroup,ou=sudoers,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: sudoRole
cn: sudogroup
sudoUser: thomas
sudoHost: ALL
sudoRunAs: ALL
sudoCommand: ALL
```

Add sudoers_base in ldap.conf for client.

```
sudoers_base ou=sudoers,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
```

& Edit /etc/nsswitch.conf like below

```
sudoers : files ldap
```

Comment: Do you have any reference we can rely on to understand that configuration?

Answer (score 0):

These instructions assume you're using OpenLDAP. Some details may be specific to Arch Linux.

1. Make sure `sudo` is built with LDAP support. (see [README.LDAP](https://www.sudo.ws/readme_ldap.html) or [this](http://pig.made-it.com/ldap-sudoers.html#327))
2. Add the sudo schema to the LDAP server by editing `slapd.conf` to add `include   /etc/openldap/schema/sudo.schema`. Note that this file must be copied from `/usr/share/doc/sudo/schema.OpenLDAP` (see README.LDAP).
3. Per README.LDAP, direct the LDAP server to index the attribute `sudoUser` by adding the line `index sudoUser eq` to `slapd.conf`, and restart the LDAP server.
4. Add the ou=SUDOers container to the database. This can be done by passing in the following via `ldapadd`:

   dn: ou=SUDOers,dc=example,dc=com
    objectClass: top
    objectClass: organizationalUnit
    ou: SUDOers
5. Convert the existing `sudoers` file to LDIF format with `cvtsudoers` add it to the database with `ldapadd` (see README.LDAP). The configuration could, of course, be generated from scratch instead.
6. Creat (or edit) `ldap.conf` (`/etc/openldap/ldap.conf` on Arch) on the client to add `sudoers_base   ou=SUDOers,dc=example,dc=com` to make sudo LDAP-aware (see [`sudoers.ldap`](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.17/sudoers.ldap.man.html)). Depending on your LDAP configuration, it may be necessary to set various LDAP options as well; sudo's syntax for setting options may be different than your LDAP implementation, so the same information may need to be provided twice.
7. Edit `sudoers` service in `nsswitch.conf` to be `sudoers: files ldap`, or to `sudoers: files sss` if caching with `SSSD` (see `sudoers.ldap manual`). If caching w/ SSSD, the necessary entries will need to be added to sssd.conf (and on systems running systemd `sssd-sudo.socket` must be enabled (see manual page for [SSSD-SUDO](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man5/sssd-sudo.5.html)))